# error while running any hadoop hdfs file system command

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am very new to hadoop and referring to the "hadoop for dummies" book. 
I have a VM with following specs: hadoop version 2.0.6-alpha bigtop os centos

The problem is when I run any hdfs file system command I get following error:

```
hadoop hdfs dfs -ls error : Could not find or load main class hdfs
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call this via `hadoop`.
You can either run:

```
hdfs dfs -ls /
```

Or:

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

Comment: thanks faker this worked. can you please clarify what was the meaning of hadoop written before command. bcoz it is written in this only in book.

Comment: it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it's going to answer your question but

```
  Hadoop version 1
```

All command line utilities were in 'hadoop install dir'/bin directory.
All hadoop commands are invoked by the bin/hadoop script

```
  Hadoop version 2
  Commands live in two directories.

bin : Most used commands like hadoop, mapred ..etc
sbin: Administrative commands like start-all.sh (command used to start all Hadoop daemons ..etc) and stop-all.sh
```